# DB Connection Management in AWS Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using AWS Lambda to build out my API. I decided to go with a monolith architecture to minimize cold starts. I'm using express.js for routing and the mysqljs library to connect to my database. The API is into different folders: routes, controllers and models:

```
my-app
├── index.js
├── controllers
├── models
└── routes
```

I'm using the serverless framework and serverless-offline for local development.

One problem I have been having is with my database connection pools. And I think the problem is because serverless-offline and lambda functions behave differently and in ways I don't fully understand. I have gone through several different approaches.

The current is I create the pool in `index.js`, inside the `exports.handler`, and then pass it to the routes, which passes it to the routes, which passes it to the controllers which passes it to the models. When the model returns the to the controller and I call `res.json()` and `pool.end()`.

This works well in serverless-offline, but when I call the API from inside the Lambda function, the first time it works fine, but the second time I get `Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit`. I thought every API call would be a new 'invocation'.

Comment: Its weird: on Lambda, when I require the pool from the database.js file, it gives a reference to the same object. In local, it gives me a new pool object

Comment: Related topic: https://www.jeremydaly.com/reuse-database-connections-aws-lambda/